# How to remove text before header in r

Tags: r

I have a text file I want to work on. However before I get the the dataset I want to import there is a load of text that I want to strip away. Each line of the text I want to remove starts with a @ symbol but there can be different number of pre-data text lines. How can I strip away this pre-data text. For example:

```
@HD VN:1.0  SO:unsorted
@SQ SN:chr1 LN:249250621
@SQ SN:chr2 LN:243199373
@SQ SN:chr3 LN:198022430
@SQ SN:chr4 LN:191154276
@SQ SN:chr5 LN:180915260
@SQ SN:chr6 LN:171115067
@SQ SN:chr7 LN:159138663
@SQ SN:chr8 LN:146364022
@SQ SN:chr9 LN:141213431
@SQ SN:chr10    LN:135534747
@SQ SN:chr11    LN:135006516
@SQ SN:chr12    LN:133851895
@SQ SN:chr13    LN:115169878
@SQ SN:chr14    LN:107349540
@SQ SN:chr15    LN:102531392
@PG ID:Bowtie   VN:1.1.0    
Number chr locus
 1      1    10092
 2      12   12313
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are no instances of "@" that you want to keep, you can set "@" as the comment character to skip those lines

```
read.table("data.txt", comment="@", header=T)
```

Comment: Definitely the easiest

Answer (score 2):

Two quick methods:

#### Inefficient but All "*R*"

```
wholeFile <- readLines('user3632206.csv')
partialFile <- wholeFile[! grepl('^@', wholeFile)]
parsedFile <- read.table(textConnection(partialFile), header = TRUE)
parsedFile
##   Number chr locus
## 1      1   1 10092
## 2      2  12 12313
```

#### Preprocess on the Command-Line

On the command line, using `grep` (native in MacOS and unix, can be found for windows in several packages including cygwin, msys, msys2, etc):

```
bash$ grep -v '^@' user3632206.csv > user3632206-filtered.csv
```

And in R:

```
parsedFile <- read.table('user3632206-filtered.csv', header = TRUE)
parsedFile
##   Number chr locus
## 1      1   1 10092
## 2      2  12 12313
```

Comment: I like the all in R answer as its much neater but grepping the whole file takes ages. Is there a way of reading in only the first 50 lines and grepping from that and then importing the whole file?

Comment: Sure, use `n=50` in the call to `readLines`, find the number of lines to skip, and pass it in a `skip=` argument, very similar to @rawr's answer. (That's a lot more efficient than mine, which does *not* assume that all lines to skip are in the beginning.)

Comment: (+1): nice answers. I like the cmd line - you can use `pipe` in `read.table` to save creating the extra file (i think): `read.table(pipe("grep -v '^@' test.txt"), header=TRUE)`

Comment: Nice! Never used it. (Of course, many of my colleagues are on windows, and I'm never certain if they have those admittedly critical tools available.)